# Marketing Cloud Data Extension Consistency Model

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a Data Extension that will be updated by multiple users using either REST API or through Marketing Cloud flow. We want to understand what will happen to the REST call to update particular Records if some other user is also trying to update the same Record. What atomicity/consistency policy MC has for the Data Extension. Eg REST API we will be accessing is: PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/key:{key}/rows/{primaryKeys}

Answer (score 1):

You will **not** get a 'this record is currently being edited' type of message. Calls will be processed in the order they are received.

Comment: IF 2 calls are made (which the calls tend to be sync, not async, by default) to the same row at nearly the same time, the second one will fail, not queue and process. To get what you mention above, I believe you would need to ensure all are utilizing Async - but even then, your second call potentially could be overwriting what the first call edited previously.